# Nginx is creating a 403 Forbidden error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I have the following code in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, which for some reason is creating a 403 error when I go to my domain:

Code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/site;
    index landing.html;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /landing.html;
            index landing.html;
    }
}
```

What could be creating this problem? Also note that I replaced the actual domain with site.com for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified that the root for this configuration is `/home/site`

This is probably due to file permission. Check whether `/home/site/landing.html` has the correct file permissions.

Optimal permission would be 644 (rw-r--r--). Hence use `chmod 644 /home/site/landing.html`

Comment: And all parent folders should have `x` permission. Usually home folders don't have one for *others*

Comment: Since the folder site is located in home, I assume it was created upon user creation, hence it should have execute (x) permission by default.

Comment: For owner yes. For other users (like nginx or www-data), probably no. On fresh linux installations it's usually `drwx------`

Comment: Anyway, OP should check them too

Comment: After following your steps, it says the permissions are `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root`

Comment: This is for landing.html ? If you still have the 403 error, check if the parent folder /home/site is having 755 permission (drwxr-xr-x) or set it using chmod 755 /home/site/ or recursive using chmod -R 755 /home/site/